# What does the `.EXT` mean in kohana index file?

Tags: php, indexing, kohana

I'm a MVC n00b learning Kohana via online tutorials.

I'm looking at a file called `index.php`.

What is the `.EXT` for (what does it mean?) in the following line?

```
// Bootstrap the application
require APPPATH.'bootstrap'.EXT;
```

Comment: `EXT` is a constant, `.` is a concatenation operator.

Comment: why is this such a bad question?

Comment: This question seems fine to me. It is well formatted, asks a specific question, and has a single non-discursive answer. +1 and voting to reopen. cc: @dwstein

Comment: @dwstein because "you are looking at a file called index.php" and that very file defines the constant and documents what it's for, so the answer is rhetorical.

Comment: @Gordon You got me, I didn't see the definition in the file.  My error.  I will tell you, however, for a n00b like me, it can be very hard to pick out the relavant code, because I'm still learning what to look for.  Also, when someone provides a good answer like the one below, it's an opportunity to learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the *default extension* (.php) as you can see in the [index.php](https://github.com/kohana/kohana/blob/3.3/master/index.php#L32)

```
/**
 * The default extension of resource files. If you change this, all resources
 * must be renamed to use the new extension.
 *
 * @link http://kohanaframework.org/guide/about.install#ext
 */
define('EXT', '.php');
```

You could change it to any other value, e.g. `.kohana.php` and then your bootstrap would have to be named `bootstrap.kohana.php`